# Forge viewer,not responding from server

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

Since 2016.12.7 afternoon the forge servers are not responding to my API calls related to forge viewer,It only responding to the authentication API.I tried to load viewer with error handling functions it returns a error "onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:6".Please can any one help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update, Dec 8, 2016**

The Forge Data Management and Model Derivative APIs are now back online, including access to data via the API for Fusion Team, A360 and BIM 360 Docs. The Forge team apologizes for the current outage and any problems it has caused for you and your customers.

We are now investigating all aspects of this outage to prevent it from happening in the future.

Please check our [API Status page](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/support/api-status).

**Original, on Dec 7, 2016**

We are experiencing an issue of Forge Forge Data Management and Model Derivative APIs. The two APIs are currently unavailable. [This is the detailed announcement](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/12/data-management-outage.html).

We apologize any inconvenience that caused to you. We will keep you updated once the APIs are recovered. Appreciate for your patience and understanding!